# Can't access IP address from outside localhost

Tags: windows-server-2008

So I have this dedicated server with Windows Server 2008, created today. I did just install Xampp, and this works fine on localhost (via remote). When i'm trying to connect to the IP address from my personal computer it will not work.

My guess is of course that I need to do some configurations, but I'm completely new and I don't know what to search or look for. Any ideas would be very appreciated.

**Just to be clear: nothing on the server has been changed. Just installed Xampp.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow traffic through the Windows Firewall to whatever ports your Apache installation is listening on. Most likely, these ports are going to be 80 and 443.

Comment: I added port 80 in the "inbound rules" and it works as far as I see. Is there anything more to change?

Comment: If you plan on using SSL, then you should add 443. If not, then 80 will cover all HTTP traffic.

Comment: If this solved your issue, you should click the check mark to the left of this answer to accept it.

Comment: Had to wait for some minutes then I forgot. Accepted:)